# Are there equivalents to pread on different platforms?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, cross-platform

I am writing a concurrent, persistent message queue in C++, which requires concurrent read access to a file without using memory mapped io. Short story is that several threads will need to read from different offsets of the file.

Originally I had a file object that had typical read/write methods, and threads would acquire a mutex to call those methods. However, it so happened that I did not acquire the mutex properly somewhere, causing one thread to move the file offset during a read/write, and another thread would start reading/writing to an incorrect part of the file.

So, the paranoid solution is to have one open file handle per thread. Now I've got a lot of file handles to the same file, which I'm assuming can't be great.

I'd like to use something like [pread](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_pread.htm), which allows passing in of the current offset to read/write functions.

However, the function is only available on linux, and I need equivalent implementations on windows, aix, solaris and hpux, any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you write your own pread() for other platforms?  There doesn't seem anything there you can't do with a fseek() type function.

Comment: @Duck: What Snazzer wants is something that will seek and read in one atomic operation.

Comment: The man page doesn't indicate pread() does that. Would any system offer an atomic seek/read on a regular file? Even using pread() he would have to provide his own lock before calling it

Comment: pread takes the offset as a parameter, so I'm assuming that it's to allow for atomic seek-then-read/write operations on a shared file handle. Googling around seems to indicate that...or am I missing something? Otherwise there seems little use for pread if it cannot be used with multiple threads.

Comment: @Snazzer:  My apologies.  It is atomic and actually quite cool.  I need to play with it a bit more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, the [ReadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx) function can do it, see the `lpOverlapped` parameter and [this info on async IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686358(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Looks like this would work, seems that the overlapped parameter is still used even for synchronous file access. Thanks jpalecek!

Answer (score 4):

With NIO, `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` has a `read(ByteBuffer dst, long position)` method, which internally uses `pread`.

Oh wait, your question is about C++, not Java. Well, I just looked at the JDK source code to see how it does it for Windows, but unfortunately on Windows it isn't atomic: it simply seeks, then reads, then seeks back.

For Unix platforms, the punchline is that `pread` is standard for any XSI-supporting (X/Open System Interface, apparently) operating system: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pread.html

Comment: Actually it looks like, at least now in 2023, the Windows implementation of FileChannel.read(dst, postion) looks like it just saves the file pointer but does ReadFile with an OVERLAPPED parameter indicating the position and then restores the file pointer. But the ReadFile with position is one call. So it could be atomic. Failure could result in a bad file pointer but it's not clear that it would matter if it's not being used.

Answer (score 2):

Based on another answer, the closest I could come up with is this.  However, there is a bug: ReadFile will change the file offset, and pread is guaranteed to not change the file offset.  There's no real way to fix this, because code can do normal read() and write() concurrently with no lock.  Anybody found a call that will not change the offset?

```
unsigned int FakePRead(int fd, void *to, std::size_t size, uint64_offset) {
  // size_t might be 64-bit.  DWORD is always 32.
  const std::size_t kMax = static_cast<std::size_t>(1UL << 31);
  DWORD reading = static_cast<DWORD>(std::min<std::size_t>(kMax, size));
  DWORD ret;
  OVERLAPPED overlapped;
  memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
  overlapped.Offset = static_cast<DWORD>(off);
  overlapped.OffsetHigh = static_cast<DWORD>(off >> 32);
  if (!ReadFile((HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd), to, reading, &ret, &overlapped)) {
    // TODO: set errno to something?
    return -1;
  }
  // Note the limit to 1 << 31 before.
  return static_cast<unsigned int>(ret);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I was able to confirm that ReadFile() does change the file offset, at least on Windows 7. I used SetFilePointerEx() to read the offset.