# infinite loop in while loop

Tags: c, loops, infinite

```
fp=fopen("Product.dat","rb+");
while (fread(&prod,sizeof (prod),1,fp)==1) {
    prod.stockquant = prod.stockquant + prod.stockorderquant;
    prod.stockorderquant = 0;
    fseek(fp, -sizeof(prod), SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite (&prod, sizeof(prod), 1, fp);
}
fclose (fp);
```

Once I get into the while loop, I am getting an infinite loop.
The file pointer is fp, the prod is an instance of Struct called PRODUCT, stockquant and stockorderquant ara variables in the struct. I am attempting to change the values of stockquant and stockorderquant. This is a batch update tht im doing for my project. I am trying to go through the whole file called product.dat while editing each product's stockquant and orderquant.

Why am I getting an infinite loop? 
This method seems to work when I use it in an if statement that checks if the prod.id = userinput or not.

Any help?

Some extra code:

```
void batchupdate(void) { 
    system("cls");
    FILE *fp;
    int c=0;
    gotoxy(20,4);
    printf("****Batch Update Section****");
    char another='y';
    while(another=='y')
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(15,6);
        printf("Are you sure you want to Batch update (Press Y or N)?");

        if((getch()=='y') || (getch() == 'Y')) {
        system("cls");
        int pos;

        fp=fopen("Product.dat","rb+");
        while(fread(&prod,sizeof(prod),1,fp)==1) {
                prod.stockquant = prod.stockquant + prod.stockorderquant;
                product.stockorderquant = 0;

                fseek(fp, -(sizeof(prod)), SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite (&prod, sizeof(prod), 1, fp);
                getchar();
                pos = ftell(fp);
                printf("%d",&pos);


        }
        fclose (fp);

        gotoxy(15,16);
        printf("Complete");
        gotoxy(15,18);
        printf("All products stock quantity have been updated. The stock order quantity has been reset");

        gotoxy(15,16);
        printf("Do you want to modify another product?(Y/N)");
        fflush(stdin);
        another=getch() ; }

    else { if((getch()=='n') || (getch() == 'N')) {
                mainmenu();
           }
    }
}
    returnfunction();
}
```

This is how I list my products (and it works!) (Please not the order quantity displayed here has nothing to do with the stockorderquant

```
void listproduct(void)  
{
    int x;
    FILE *fp;
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(1,1);
    printf("*********************************Product List*****************************");
    gotoxy(2,2);
    printf("Name              ID    Price  StockQuant  Order Quant  Description");
    x=4;
    fp=fopen("Product.dat","rb");
    while(fread(&prod,sizeof(prod),1,fp)==1){
        gotoxy(2,x);
        printf("%s",prod.prodname);
        gotoxy(20,x);
        printf("%d",prod.prodid);
        gotoxy(26,x);
        printf("%.2f",prod.price);
        gotoxy(34,x);
        printf("%d",prod.stockquant);
        gotoxy(46,x);
        printf("%d",prod.orderquantity);
        gotoxy(59,x);
        printf("%s",prod.description);
        printf("\n\n");
        x++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    gotoxy(35,25);
    returnfunction();
}
```

my struct is defined like below:

```
struct PRODUCT
{
    int id;
    char name[30];
    char desc[50];
    float price;
    int stockquant;
    int orderquant;
    int stockorderquant;
};

struct PRODUCT prod;
```

Comment: Please don't use the homework tag. It's [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: someone else today told me to use it.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri That someone else apparently isn't au courant. The homework tag is indeed deprecated since last fall.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri: There is general disagreement on that one.  I for one think it should stay.  However, it is officially deprecated.

Comment: can someone please help me? lol the homework tag is no longer there :D yay

Comment: hint, what happens if you print the current position in the file each iteration of the loop (with, say ftell).

Comment: Check the return values of functions for errors.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of this and need it to be fast, you may want to consider using the old-skool I/O routines.  See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171052/what-goes-on-behind-the-curtains-during-disk-i-o) related to this.

Comment: i better fix this prob first mate

Comment: cmh:

I had 3 items and I got 2686672, with ftell(fp) now I created new file with 4 items and I'm getting 2686208 with every iteration

Comment: `printf("%d",&pos);` <- you're printing the address of `pos`, remove the `&`. And add a `pos = ftell(fp); printf("%d\n",pos);` before and after the `fseek` too to see that that does what it is supposed to.

Comment: 100
100200
200300
300400
400500
500600
600700

this is what im getting. it seems like it is actually getting the file bigger by the infinite loop

Comment: Yes, it's getting bigger. Now to find out why.

Comment: Can you add some debug info, `"Before fseek"`, `"After fseek"`, `"After fwrite"` to the printouts of `pos`?

Comment: before fseek 100 after fseek 0 after fwrite 100
before fseek 200 after fseek 100 after fwrite 200
before fseek 300 after fseek 200 after fwrite 300

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22492/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-jurgen-cuschieri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me quote the man page for `fopen`:

> Reads and writes may be intermixed on read/write streams in any  order. Note  that  ANSI  C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters  end-of-file. (If this condition is not met, then a read is allowed to return the result of writes other than the most recent.)  Therefore it is good practice  (and  indeed  sometimes  necessary  under  Linux)  to  put an `fseek(3)` or `fgetpos(3)` operation between write and read  operations  on such  a  stream.   This  operation  may  be  an  apparent  no-op (as in
>    `fseek(..., 0L, SEEK_CUR)` called for its synchronizing side effect.

Calling `fseek` after the write,

```
fseek(fp, -sizeof(prod), SEEK_CUR);
fwrite (&prod, sizeof(prod), 1, fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

ought to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
fseek(fp, -sizeof(prod), SEEK_CUR);
```

will move the current pointer `sizeof(prod)` before the current file pointer, and the next read will read the same record, and move before, etc.

Hece, the infinite loop.

Practicallym it reads all the time only the first record.

Comment: But `fwrite(&product, sizeof(prod), 1, fp)` will return the pointer to the start of the next record to read, wont it?

Comment: if I remove it I still get an infinite loop!

Comment: The loop 1. reads a record, 2. moves the file pointer back, 3. writes a record. That should move the file pointer one record forward altogether, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

```
fwrite (&product, sizeof(prod), 1, fp);
```

Is trying to store a struct called `product`, and not `prod` in the file, and may be returning an error (not checked) that will prevent the pointer to move to the next record to read, making this code read once and again the same record.

You should store the `prod` variable you just changed, and dont forget to check for errors

```
if (fwrite (&prod, sizeof(prod), 1, fp)==-1)
    perror("fwrite error");
```

Comment: actually I had changed that before. i also edited up here. i still get the infinite loop

Comment: don't forget that when I get into the while loop, it immediately goes into infinite loop mode,therefore that point of the source code is unreachable

Comment: So... the while loop doesn't do **any** of its sentences? not even a `printf("hello\n")`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have problems with the value `-sizeof(prod)` because `sizeof` returns an unsigned value.  When you negate this, it becomes a very large value, and then you implicitly cast it to `long int`.

Try this:

```
fseek(fp, -(int)sizeof(prod), SEEK_CUR);
```

Also, you need to test that your `fwrite` succeeded or you will keep rewinding.

Comment: But fseek expects a long, so the implicit cast to long int should do the correct thing.

Comment: It would be unusual if that really caused the problem. Usually, `sizeof(size_t) >= sizeof(long)`, and the conversion from `size_t` to `long` just reinterprets the appropriate number of bits. Unless `sizeof(prod)` is huge, that would result in the same value as `-(long)sizeof(prod)`.

Comment: Yeah I realised that after posting.

Comment: no thats surely not causing the problem, cause its working in other methods. thanks for posting anyways :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have an infinite loop, you always reseek the file position indicator:

```
fseek(fp, -sizeof(prod), SEEK_CUR);
```

So you read one element then reseek it and always read the same element, infinitely.

Comment: I hope that sizeof(prod) is 1. what do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

Second default argument type of fseek() in 'long'. You need to type cast it to 'long' i.e. 
fseek(fp, -(long) sizeof(prod), SEEK_CUR);