# Basic file I/O in C++ for random R/W of byte chunks

Tags: c++, file, file-io, stream, binary

I'm porting a low-level file I/O library from Java to C++, and I need some help with basic file I/O in C++. Currently the API looks like:

```
public class BinaryFile {

    // open/close the file stream
    public BinaryFile(string path, string mode)
    public void Close()

    // append to the end of file
    public void AppendBytes(byte[] bytes, uint readPos, uint length)

    // write a certain byte chunk at a certain position into the file
    public void WriteBytes(byte[] bytes, uint readPos, uint length, uint writePos)

    // read a certain byte chunk from the file
    public byte[] ReadBytes(uint position, uint length)
}
```

Firstly, I've been through all the 5 different ways you can access files/file streams in C/C++ and I really don't care which method I go with (`fread` and friends may be fine). As you can see I need to randomly read/write binary chunks from any part of a file, and so `fgets` would not be a good fit since it writes a length prefix.

However, since I'm somewhat new to C++, is there a library or header file that already has a similar API? (please, not a monolithic framework like boost) In short I just need to read, write and append binary chunks to a binary file. No sweat, no strings, no JSON, no XML, nothing complex. Whats the easiest way to achieve this in VC++ 2010? I've got Visual Studio 2010.

**Edit:** I'm targeting Windows XP+ and building a DLL, and I'm already including `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>` and `<windows.h>` with `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.

Comment: If you want a file stream, there is `<fstream>`. The interface of course is slightly different.

Comment: I don't specifically want a file stream. Anything is file. A file pointer such as `FILE *` may be fine too. As I said I don't really care about the API, I just want to know how to read, write and append binary chunks to a binary file.

Comment: What is `read(2)` and `write(2)`? You mean this? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

Comment: I wasn't paying attention that you were on Windows, and it was kind of a joke anyway. They are system calls, and would be ReadFile and WriteFile on Windows. But FILE* from cstdio is probably as simple as you can get while remaining platform independent.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I've edited my question. Can you check if that changes your suggestions? Can you also add your suggestions with a simple 5 LOC VC++ sample showing how to either read, write or append to a file using whatever API you propose? or link to a tutorial that does what I want? (already searching google for the last hour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`FILE*` APIs from `<cstdio>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct foo {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
};

int main(void)
{
    // connect to the file
    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
    if (!f)
        return 1;

    // use "unbuffered mode" since you are doing random access
    setbuf(f, NULL );

    // declare an array of 2 objects
    struct foo data[] = { 
        { .a = 0xDEADBEEF, .b = 0x2B84F00D },
        { .a = 0xCAFEBABE, .b = 0xBAADB0B1 },
    };  

    // write the data
    fwrite(&data, sizeof(struct foo), 2, f); 

    // move to byte 0x20
    fseek(f, 0x20, SEEK_SET);

    // write an ASCII string
    fprintf(f, "ASCII TOO");

    // disconnect from the file
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Hexdump of `test.bin`:

```
00000000  ef be ad de 0d f0 84 2b  be ba fe ca b1 b0 ad ba  |.......+........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  41 53 43 49 49 20 54 4f  4f                       |ASCII TOO|
00000029
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the clear and concise answer. I'm just gonna add some comments, obvious, but still. BTW, the `fopen` APIs are simple and clean. I prefer them over the streaming stuff that I don't really need. (I need random access)

Comment: @Geotarget "`fopen` API" is also stream-oriented, not for random access :-) Of course, you can reposition file pointer, but this is a stream access anyway.

Comment: @vladon - Andrew Henle in his answer below said that if you use "unbuffered mode" then the streaming/buffering turns off. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: @Geotarget No, I talk about stream as programming principle. Stream is always one-way object. You can read it in one direction. Simply you can swim in physical real stream, but can not swim back. You can read N bytes, read 1 byte, read 1 bit etc. Same with write. You do read or write and reposition only in one direction (forward). That is the definition of stream in programming.

Comment: @Geotarget And I want to add that file access by its nature is stream access (hard disk head is positioned and then read only sequentially).

Answer (score 3):

- You can use C-style `fwrite` and `fread` from `<cstdio>` header or streams from C++ .
- You can use WinAPI [File Management Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx), see [example at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx).
- Also, you can use [Asio standalone](http://think-async.com/Asio/Download) - and its file operations. May be harder.

Anyway, C/C++ standard libraries both think about files as streams, and not as random-access resource.

Your class public part may look like this:

```
class BinaryFile
{
public:
    BinaryFile(const std::string & path, const std::string & mode);
    ~BinaryFile();

    void AppendBytes(const std::vector<uint8_t> & bytes, size_t readPos, size_t length);

    void WriteBytes(const std::vector<uint8_t> & bytes, size_t readPos, size_t length, size_t writePos);

    std::vector<uint8_t> ReadBytes(size_t position, size_t length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "best" answer is highly dependent on how you access your data.  Other answers already cover what you API might look like, so I'm just going to focus on implementation details.

First, Windows does not appear to provide atomic seek-and-read or seek-and-write operations such as [POSIX `pread()` and `pwrite()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) - which atomically read from or write to a specified offset in a file without modifying the file's offset.  (See [Are there equivalents to pread on different platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766477/are-there-equivalents-to-pread-on-different-platforms))  So if you're targeting a multithreaded environment, it's going to be really hard to make your API reentrant and multithread-safe without adding locking.

Second, given your requirement for *random* access, the buffering built into streaming-based solutions (C++ streams, `<cstdio>` `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc.) could have a significant negative impact on performance.  For example, if you use `<cstdio>` operations that buffer 8k, each time you `fseek()` on the `FILE *`, you will likely invalidate the associated buffer.  If you're only reading a handful of bytes at a time, the buffer invalidations on each seek-then-read will result in a significant multiplication of the number of bytes your process reads.

I'd recommend using `fread()`/`fwrite()`, optionally using unbuffered IO depending on your access pattern.  You can disable buffering with `setbuf()`:

```
FILE *file = ::fopen(...);
setbuf( file, NULL );
```

in your case, see the [MSDN documentation for `setbuf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fbt032s.aspx).

One advantage of using unbuffered IO is that applications calling your API might assume data is safely written to disk upon each call, but in the case of normal buffered `<cstdio>` isn't.

Comment: +5 - I would vote this up 5 times if I could. Really in-depth answer. I would have ticked this one if it had a complete code sample (that's not an indirect way of asking you to add one, your answer is great as-is).